# Retorno JSON não retorna em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, restful

Estava com uma API retornando os dados corretamente, mas o mesmo parou do nada.

A instrução SQL quando executada no Wrockbrench funciona. As demais APIs seguem este mesmo padrão a seguir. Mas não está retornando. E estava retornando antes, não sei o que mudei que não mostra nada do resultado. Seguem os códigos:

Meu DAO:

```
<?php

class MensagemDAO {

    private $conexao;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conexao = new Conexao();
    }

    public function consultarMensagens() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE enviado = 1";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao->getCon(), $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
            return $resultado;      
        } else {
            return false;            
        }
    }

    public function consultarCodigo($codigo) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE idmensagens = '$codigo'";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao->getCon(), $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
            return $resultado;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function consultarPremioMes() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM premio_mes WHERE NOW() >= data_inicio AND NOW() <= data_fim";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao->getCon(), $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
            return $resultado;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Minha API de Retorno com JSON:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
//    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }

    exit(0);
}

header('Content-type: application/json'); 


include "./../Classes/Conexao.php";
include './../Classes/DAO/MensagemDAO.php';


$MensagemDAO = new MensagemDAO();

$consulta = $MensagemDAO->consultarMensagens();

if ($consulta == true) {    
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($consulta); $i++) {
        $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

        $respostas [] = array(
            'idmensagens' => $linha['idmensagens'],
            'subject' => $linha['subject'],
            'message' => $linha['message'],
            'enviado' => $linha['enviado']
        );
    }
}else{
    echo 'sem resultado';
}


echo json_encode($respostas);
?>
```

Segue a estrutura da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não tem nenhum versionamento de código para ver as últimas alterações dos arquivos?

Comment: A importância de um controle de versões meu amigo!

Comment: @fernandosavio postei sem ver seu comentário...rs

Comment: É nessas horas que o VCS brilha

Comment: Era um problema de acentuação....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era um erro de acentuação: não listava o que tinha acentuação. Estava tudo certo.

Mas vou deixar esta pergunta em aberto, sem fechar como solucionada, para dar espaço a quem der uma resposta bacana.